# Removing code entirely from an svn repository

Tags: svn

We have an SVN server (v. 1.6.11) on a Linux box.  One of our developers accidentally committed code to repository x, which should have been in repository y.

We now have to make available to a client, the contents of repository x, and the 'wrong' code commits need to be removed, so as not to breach confidentiality agreements.

svnadmin dump repo_y > filename.dump

.. fine.  But how do I remove the incorrect code before reimporting the dump?

Many thanks.

Comment: http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal

Comment: possible duplicate of [It is possible to completely remove a file from my SVN repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1111346/it-is-possible-to-completely-remove-a-file-from-my-svn-repository)

Comment: Dumped the repo, ran it through svndumpfilter and then reloaded it.  Got 'database locked'.