# How to completely delete a directory from an SVN repository

Tags: svn

We committed some files in the `/foo` path. Now we want to start the `/foo` history from scratch. How do we delete `/foo` and its history from svn? It is possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is not made easy by SVN, as it is designed to preserve data at all costs, not destroy it. There is no harm in leaving `foo's` history in the repository.

You can, however, do this using [`svnadmin dump`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.reposadmin.maint.html#svn.reposadmin.maint.filtering). You will find some details here:

[Subversion Obliterate feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560684/svn-obliterate)

Answer (score 1):

If you delete the foo path, and create it later, it will not show the history of the old foo. But the history of the old foo path will remain, as answered by RedFilter.