# Is it possible to delete content in a subversion repository?

Tags: svn, repository

Is it possible to delete a file from subversion repository completely including the history? The problem are illegal files without the needing copyright.

How can I do it?

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560684/svn-obliterate

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, sorry. This is the much planned but not-yet-implemented `svn obliterate` feature on the mailing list.

The best you can do is to take a complete repository dump with `svnadmin dump`, filter out the files you want to remove and then `svnadmin load` it into a clean repository. There is a script `svndumpfilter` included in the distribution; I don't think that can filter out individual files as-is but it's a good starting point. As far as I remember the script can't cope with `--deltas` dumps, though, so you might have to stick with `--incremental`.