# Delete Tortoise SVN Commits

Tags: tortoisesvn

I messed up with some commits in my project and I'd like to totally remove the commits I made, and not having any trace anymore (no revert).

Because I deleted some folders in my arborescence then restored them, but I lost all the logs that were on these subfolders and I totally need to know the modifications that have been made on these subfolders.

From the main folder, all the logs are visible, but not anymore in the subfolders

Does someone has an idea how to do it ???

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to delete content in subversion repository?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4223879/is-it-possible-to-delete-content-in-subversion-repository)

Answer (score 0):

You cannot remove revisions, but I think what you could to in your case is the following: Use the repository browser and go to the revision where you still had your folders, copy the required folders to some "temp" folder in the root of your repository. Switch back to the "HEAD" of the repository and move the copied folders back into your project folder.

This way you will be able to see the entire history, just make sure that you uncheck the "Stop on copy/rename" checkbox in the log window.