# SVN accidently committed file with password

Tags: tortoisesvn

Short question:
I've been very stupid and accidently commited a file with a password (in plain text) in it that I really do NOT want on the SVN server.
So I panicked, deleted the password and commited again, but it's still in the log...

I permanently want to delete this password from the server, so it can't be retrieved by anyone anymore.

Is this possible?

If I revert to a version before the password and commit again, will it be deleted forever?

Comment: Not via "official SVN means". I made the same mistake some time ago and deleted the string from the diffs that the SVN server (we use FSFS repos) stores. This is the only way to completely remove it.

Comment: Try the approach given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4735723/309086 and here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/560684/309086

Comment: @Christoph manually editing the FSFS store is a dangerous proposition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reverting to version before & committing again will not help as log(history) is still maintained.

There is a Question and answer in FAQ of subversion

**- http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal**

, it describes how you can remove a file from the repository's history. However it requires admin access to the SVN reporsitory.

Personally I suggest "change the password" as suggested in comments by Mitch.
Also [another question on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560684/subversion-obliterate-feature) is useful.