# Configure subversion to not store past versions of a file

Tags: svn, large-files

I have a large binary file which due to integration/automation issues I need to check into subversion. It makes no sense to track past versions of this file. Is there a way I could tell subversion to only store the latest revision and delete past revisions?

Comment: If this is a batch file, you could simply delete everything but the HEAD of the given file. You know that it does not store full copies of the file right?

Comment: Is there a way to do that aside from using svnadmin dump/load?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't currently any decent way of doing this.  You need an `svn obliterate`-type function which I believe [hasn't been written yet](http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal).  Several people have written various scripts to achieve similar results, eg [Subversion Obliterate feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560684/svn-obliterate) but the general principle is the same: dump the svn database, pipe through a filter and back into `svnadmin load`, which I suspect may be more work than you're looking for.

Comment: I suspect that your solution is as good as it gets. Not an option for me unfortunately.

Comment: I think your other option is for something more pragmatic, eg instead of checking the binaries into SVN create a consistent naming scheme (eg 'build_13', or '2011-12-06') and copy them over to a file server. You can then manually delete the ones you no longer need.

Comment: I remember looking into `svn obliterate` a year ago or so, I don't think they're ever going to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

> Subversion 1.6 also introduced support for external definitions for
>   files. File externals are configured just like externals for
>   directories and appear as a versioned file in the working copy

tells [SVNBook](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html)

It solves one part of task  - don't store future revisions of file, which can be placed outside repo  but still be accessible